# Entity Framework Core: use auto-generated foreign key as part of composite primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a generic class `TimeSeries<T>` which contains a list of generic state variables `State<T>`. `State<T>` contains the state at a certain time.

```
public class TimeSeries<T>
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<State<T>> States { get; set; }
}

public class State<T>
{
    [Key]
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public T State { get; set; }
}
```

Furthermore, I have two classes `IntClass` and `FloatClass`, both of which contain a time series, but of different types. To obtain two tables for TimeSeries, where one has a foreign key pointing to `IntClass` and the other one has a foreign key pointing to `FloatClass`, I have derived two more classes from `TimeSeries<T>`, each containing a property for the foreign key.

```
public class IntTimeSeries : TimeSeries<int>
{
    public int IntClassID{ get; set; }
}
public class FloatTimeSeries : TimeSeries<float>
{
    public int FloatClassID{ get; set; }
}
```

`IntClass` and `FloatClass` contain an instance of the derived classes:

```
public class IntClass
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IntTimeSeries TimeSeries { get; set; }
}
public class FloatClass
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public FloatTimeSeries TimeSeries { get; set; }
}
```

This approach generates among others the tables `State<int>` and `State<float>`. These have the (auto-generated) foreign keys `IntClassID` and `FloatClassID`, respectively. If I annotate `StateID` with `[Key]` as I have done here, then that is of course the primary key.

What I want, however, is that the primary keys are the composites `(Date, IntClassID)` and `(Date, FloatClassID)`, respectively. I need this because I sometimes need to update the values from a second database where I have only reading permission. Is this possible?

Comment: Which EF version is this?

Comment: The project is currently using core version 2.2, but I am free to upgrade it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EF-core 3 and 5, you can achieve this by modifying EF's metadata which is easily accessible in these later versions:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var stateTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(e => e.ClrType.IsConstructedGenericType
            && e.ClrType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == (typeof(State<>)))
        .ToList();
    stateTypes
        .ForEach(t => t.SetPrimaryKey(t.FindProperties(new[] { "StateID", "Date"} )));
}
```

This first collects the entity types that are derived from `State<>` and then sets the primary key properties for these types. Using `nameof` would of course make this more runtime-safe.

For EF core 2 users, the last statement would be:

```cs
    stateTypes.ForEach(t => t.SetPrimaryKey(t.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => new[] { "StateID", "Date" }.Contains(p.Name))
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.Name)
        .ToList()));
```

(`OrderByDescending` because in this case the properties aren't taken in the order of the array).

Comment: Thank you. I will upgrade the version and try it out.

Comment: Just added an EF core 2 adaptation to make this more widely applicable.

Comment: I have done the upgrade and inserted your code. Instead of `"StateID"` I inserted a function that maps `t` onto the foreign key name. That works so far. Now when I call `EnsureCreated()` on the database, it tells me that the foreign key must also be non-nullable. Do you know how I can ensure that for a generated key?

The full exception message is System.InvalidOperationException: "A key on entity type 'State<float>' cannot contain the property 'FloatClassID' because it is nullable/optional. All properties on which a key is declared must be marked as non-nullable/required."

Comment: I didn't get this error with your code, so I wonder where it's from. It may be possible to change this in the metadata as well, but I think you better make sure that all properties that may be part of PKs aren't nullable. For example, if the property itself is of type `int?` it can never be "required".

Comment: As I wrote in the question the PK that is apparently nullable is auto-generated and thus, I cannot just change `int?` to `int`. Based on your answer, however, I found a solution. I will post it as a separate comment.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Gert, I found a solution:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var stateTypes = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
        .Where(e => e.ClrType.IsConstructedGenericType
            && e.ClrType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == (typeof(State<>)))
        .ToList();
    stateTypes.ForEach(t => t.FindProperty(GeneratedForeignKeyName(t)).IsNullable = false);
    stateTypes
        .ForEach(t => t.SetPrimaryKey(t.FindProperties(new[] { GeneratedForeignKeyName(t), "Date"} )));
}

private string GeneratedForeignKeyName(IMutableEntityType t)
{
    if (t.Name.Equals(/* data type namespace here */ + ".State<float>"))
    {
        return "FloatClassID";
    }
    else if (t.Name.Equals(/* data type namespace here */ + ".State<int>"))
    {
        return "IntClassID";
    }
    else throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 7 this is now easier with the new PrimaryKey attribute. Pass it the foreign key that would be generated as a string and Entity Framework will do the rest.

```
[Table("Likes")]
[PrimaryKey("LikedId", "LikedById")]
public sealed class DataUserLike
{
    // Columns
    public required DataUser Liked { get; init; }
    public required DataUser LikedBy { get; init; }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#tabgroup_2